# How to order by day of the week using ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my controller I have:

```
  def index
    @event = Event.all(:order => 'id DESC')
  end
```

I have an attribute called `Day` with the following: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday... etc.

How do I return Events ordered by day of the week?

Note: I know this is not efficient, but I have my reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def index
  @event = Event.all(:order => 'CASE Day WHEN "Monday" THEN 1 WHEN "Tuesday" THEN 2 WHEN "Wednesday" THEN 3 WHEN "Thursday" THEN 4 WHEN "Friday" THEN 5 WHEN "Saturday" THEN 6 WHEN "Sunday" THEN 7 END')
end
```