# Ordering by day of the week

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem with ordering days of week. I tried method based on this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22365881/how-to-order-by-day-of-the-week-using-activerecord).
My code:

```
@work_schedules = WorkSchedule.order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction).order('CASE day_of_week
                WHEN "Poniedziałek" THEN 1 WHEN "Wtorek" THEN 2 WHEN "Środa" THEN 3
                WHEN "Czwartek" THEN 4 WHEN "Piątek" THEN 5 WHEN "Sobota" THEN 6
                WHEN "Niedziela" THEN 7 END').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
```

Belowe there is a error:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "Poniedziałek" does not exist
LINE 2:                 WHEN "Poniedziałek" THEN 1 WHEN "Wtorek" THE..
```

Could you explain me where is wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use single quotes `'` instead of `"`: 
`"Poniedziałek"` -> `'Poniedziałek'`